# Add css style on public function after email sent success

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm using YITH-request-quote, I want to change CSS style after the email sent.
Original public function as below :

```
public function trigger( $args ) {
        $this->raq                = $args;
        $this->raq['raq_content'] = YITH_Request_Quote()->get_raq_return();

        $recipients = (array) $this->get_recipient();

        if( $this->enable_cc ){
            $recipients[] =  $this->raq['user_email'];
        }

        $recipients = implode(',',$recipients);

        $return = $this->send( $recipients, $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );

        if ( $return ) {
            YITH_Request_Quote()->clear_raq_list();
            yith_ywraq_add_notice( __('Your request has been sent successfully','yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote'), 'success' );
        }else {
            yith_ywraq_add_notice( __( 'There was a problem in sending your request. Please try again.', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ), 'error' );
        }
    }
```

I tried to add :

```
    if ( $return ) {
       YITH_Request_Quote()->clear_raq_list();
?>
      <style>.raq-message {display:none !important;}</style>
<?php
      yith_ywraq_add_notice( __('Your request has been sent successfully','yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote'), 'success' );
```

But it is not worked.

How can I add the css style after sent email success?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add the styles to a hook, depending on where the `trigger` function is called:

```
if( $return ){
    YITH_Request_Quote()->clear_raq_list();

    // Add style to a header hook, like `wp_head` or `wp_print_styles`
    add_action( 'wp_head', function(){
        echo '<style>.raq-message { display: none !important; }</style>';
    });

    yith_ywraq_add_notice( __('Your request has been sent successfully','yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote'), 'success' );
} else {
    yith_ywraq_add_notice( __( 'There was a problem in sending your request. Please try again.', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ), 'error' );
}
```

Comment: Hi @Xhynk thanks for your advise, but it is not work.